# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac 1n−\frac 1{n+1})=0$ using epsilon-delta definition.

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac 1n−\frac 1{n+1}\right)=0$ using epsilon-delta definition.

Comment: Consider using MathJAX to format the mathematical symbols in your question, as it isn't entirely clear what you're trying to ask otherwise.

Comment: Can you show  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac 1n\right)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}-0|=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$

$$<\frac{1}{n^2}$$

Given $\epsilon>0$, we look for $N\in \Bbb N$ such that

$$n\ge N\implies \frac{1}{n(n+1)}<\epsilon$$ It is easier to look for $N$ s.t

$$n\ge N\implies \frac{1}{n^2}<\epsilon$$

or
$$n\ge N\implies n>\sqrt{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}$$

We can take $$N=\lfloor \sqrt{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}\rfloor +1.$$

Comment: You could even say  $0 \lt \frac 1n−\frac 1{n+1} \lt \frac1n$ to avoid square roots

Comment: @Henry Yes right. i used absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what it means to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = L$. By definition,

> For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n\ge N$, we have $$|a_n - L| < \epsilon.$$

From here, you need to show that there exists some natural number $N$ such that $$\left|\left({1\over n} - {1\over n+1}\right) - 0\right| < \epsilon.$$ You can say that $$\begin{align}\left|\left({1\over n} - {1\over n+1}\right) - 0\right| &= \left|{(n+1) - n\over n(n+1)}\right| \\&= {1\over n^2 + n}\\ &\le \cdots \\ &<\epsilon\end{align}$$ From here, your goal is to complete the scratchwork by being able to create another valid inequality at the $\cdots$ section. This is usually done by trying to isolate $n$ in terms of $\epsilon$. How can you reduce the number of $n$'s appearing in the 3rd to last line that allows you to have just one $n$?

Comment: ok ... How can I do it ?

Comment: @user619263 hint: note that $\displaystyle {1\over 5} \le {1\over 4}$, and $\displaystyle {1\over 7} \le {1\over 2}$. What do you notice about the fractions and the inequality in each case? Which side of the inequality does the fraction with the bigger denominator go?